# Running migration before updating model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm adding a column named `sequence` to the table, and I want to use that newly added column inside my Model class for sorting. I would like to complete the entire logic on  development side, and push it to the git repository.

My problem is that after I perform git pull on the production server, my Model class will be updated, but the migration hasn't been ran, so in the model, I need to check if the column exists. I tried through Schema, but I thought that Redis would be faster (migration sets the Redis key).

It seems to me that I have to push my changes with this check, perform a pull on the production server, run migrations, then edit Model on development side again to remove the check, and then push changes once more? Can this be done in one go? Some kind of git trigger? I would like for production server to be operational at all times.

```
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('order', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->orderBy('product_id', 'asc');
            if (Redis::get('product_operations_sequence_added')) {
                $builder->orderBy('sequence', 'asc');
            }
            $builder->orderBy('id', 'asc');
        });
    }
```

Comment: You seem to answer your own question. Yes you need to create a script that will conduct the pull and run the migrations.

Comment: @Adam, you mean like a regular bash script to perform pull only on database folder first, and then run migrate, and then regular pull?

Comment: Yes, or maybe don't have your production environment be a git repository. 1. Pull, 2. Run migrations, 3. Copy files to prod.